# GAE + GQL Limitation of Math Operation

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I believe there are restriction of math operation can be performed for GQL. The following SQL statement works in normal relational database system:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(lat_t) ) * 
cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(lng_t) )
+ sin( radians(lat_t) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM Stores HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance
```

Does anyone know how to do above SQL statement using GQL statement? or at least alternative to replace the math operation of cos, radians, sin, etc in GQL? Urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppEngine doesn't support this type of query in GQL. You can only perform simple selects on equalities and inequalities.

You can emulate geo-searching using geo-hashing, however:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/geosearch.html

Comment: You also can't select specific (computed or otherwise) columns in a query - queries return whole entities.